# Root authority in xulRunner

Tags: firefox, ssl, xulrunner

I need to embed my own Trusted Root Authority for SSL connections in my XulRunner app.
Unfortunatelly I can't find how to do this...
cert_override.txt can't help my because I don't know all the server links nor all the 
certificates that must be accepted, but they are signed by the corporate authority..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the "built-in" authorities because they are compiled into `nssckbi.dll`. Unless you use a custom XULRunner build of course and change its source code.

You can add a new authority to the user profile however, the relevant file is `cert8.db`. You could use Firefox to add a new root certificate (Options / Advanced / Encryption / View certificates / Authorities / Import) and then take the resulting `cert8.db` file for your XULRunner profile. You can add it to the default profile - copy it into the `defaults/profile` directory of your application.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answare at least it brings me forward, but are you sure that the only relevant file is cert8.db ? I've took it from my FF profile, it gets now to my profile folder when launching the xul app, but the page doesn't open...

Comment: @racer: Well, there are only three possible files, the other options being `key3.db` and `secmod.db`. I relied on [Henrik Gemal's blog post](http://gemal.dk/mozilla/files.html) for my answer since I can never remember what is stored in which of these files. But my `cert8.db` definitely contains certificates of various authorities.